# Doubt in Application of Hilbert's Theorem 90

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Using Hilbert's Theorem $90$, I was able to prove that for a field $\kappa$, $n$ an integer$>0$ prime to the characteristic of $\kappa$, and assume that there is a primitive $n-$th root of unity in $\kappa$

1. Let $K$ be a cyclic extension of $n$, then there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $K=\kappa(\alpha)$ and it satisfies an equation of the form $X^n-a$ for some $a \in \kappa$
2. Conversely, let $a \in \kappa$ Let $\alpha$ be a root of $X^n— a$. Then $\kappa(\alpha)$ is cyclic over $\kappa$, of degree $d$, $d|n$, and  $\alpha^d$ is an element of k.

**I have few many questions here**

For (1), Is it necessary that $X^n-a$ is irreducible over $\kappa$?
I think maybe yes because $\kappa(\alpha)=\frac{\kappa[x]}{(x^n-a)}$ and this implies $x^n-a$ is irreducible because $(x^n-a)$ is maximal.
If not then can I get any counterexample?

2-I am unable to prove that $\alpha^d$ is an element of $\kappa$. Here I am assumming that $|G|=d$ and I was able to embedd $G$ in the cyclic group $Z_n$

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. The degree of $k(\alpha)$ over $k$ is equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, which therefore has degree $n$. Since you say you have shown that $\alpha$ is a zero of $f=X^n-a$, of which the minimal polynomial must be a divisor, it follows that $f$ must be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, and therefore it is irreducible.
2. Let me give a hint here. Let $g$ be a generator of $G$, then $g$ maps $\alpha$ to one of its conjugates. What do the conjugates of $\alpha$ look like? What can you deduce about $g(\alpha)/\alpha$?

Comment: 1. How come? For example, the polynomial $x^3-2$ has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q}$ yet its splitting field has degree $6$. Just because the degree of extension and degree of polynomial are same doesn't imply that the polynomial is irreducible.

Comment: @permutation_matrix RP_ didn't mention splitting fields, so why are you talking about them? The fact they are using is that minimal polynomials are irreducible (by definition).

Comment: @permutation_matrix Indeed splitting fields don't come into it at all. What I am saying is this: first, you know the field extension has degree $n$; second, you have a generator $\alpha$ of the field extension which satisfies an $n$-th degree polynomial $f$. Then it immediately follows that this polynomial $f$ is irreducible: indeed, it must be divisible by the minimal polynomial $f^\alpha$ of $\alpha$, which is irreducible by definition, and which has degree $n$ since the field extension has degree $n$. But $f$ itself has degree $n$, so $f=f^\alpha$.